# How to make expect wait for exec until a result is output

Tags: bash, expect

I have a script to wait for a value in 60 seconds

```
getotp.sh
        for i in {1..60}; do
        OTP=$(curl http://somewhere/somefile)
        [ ! -z "$OTP" ] && echo $OTP && exit
        sleep 1
        done
```

And I have a expect script calling the shellscript to input the OTP value.

```
spawn -ignore HUP start_vpn 
set OTP [ exec getotp.sh ]
expect "Password:" { send \$OTP\r }
expect "Connected." { expect_background }
```

start_vpn is representing a connector that will mail a OTP to me which I would like to grab (solved) and automatically prompt to the spawned interface.

The problem here is that the getotp.sh will need to wait for an undeterminable period of time (maybe 10~60 seconds) until the email is arrived and converted into the OTP value.  But 
In my expect script the line never waits:

```
set OTP [ exec getotp.sh ]
```

It never waits and the $OTP is always a null value immediately prompted to the "Password:".

How to make the expect script wait for the exectuion of getotp.sh until a proper value was acquired ?

Comment: what happens if you give `-s -f` options to curl?

Comment: The curl part is not an issue, getotp.sh gets expected result when running alone, but can't get expected result combined with expect,

Comment: what happens if you give the `-s -f` options to curl and call the expect script?

Comment: Are you sure your script *isn't* waiting for `getotp.sh`, and that the script is simply exiting immediately for some reason? Note that `exec` is probably using `/bin/sh` to execute your script, and `{1..60}` isn't guaranteed to expand to a sequence of 60 numbers.

Comment: all right, I was enabling debug mode by expect -d -f script.exp, and found the funny bug in the for syntax.  


This won't work:`for i in {1..60}; do`  

This works:`for i=$(seq 1 60); do`


The original problem was solved with this minor fix.

Comment: Please remove your question or post and accept your fix as a solution

Comment: take a look at [sexpect (Expect for Shells)](https://github.com/clarkwang/sexpect) which you can use to write *Expect* scripts with **shell code only**.